# VNC just one screen from Windows to Mac

Tags: windows, macos, mac, multiple-monitors, vnc

I'm looking to connect to a Mac system via VNC from a Windows system, but am looking for the feature similar to what is present in Apple Remote Desktop where I can choose which screen to show.

The Mac systems I am trying to connect to have an external monitor display that is hooked up to a projector, and since that monitor is full HD resolution, I was looking to omit that from the VNC connection as I only need to see the primary monitor to access the Operating System.

Every VNC client I've tried (TightVNC, RealVNC Free, TigerVNC) that supports Mac OS X authentication over VNC (I couldn't get UltraVNC to authenticate), will not let me specify the target monitor, so the connection is pretty slow.

The target system is a remote site connected via VPN, so connection speed is an important concern.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Each specific screen should be accessible using specific ports (5901, 5902, ...). However, you'd then also get the Mac's resolution on the Windows client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into Nulana's Remotix. I haven't tested it with dual monitors, but it's listed on the features page.

It's as fast or faster than the Native Apple Client.